# VS2015 to handle ES6 multi-line template literal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Short Question:**

Is there any way to make Visual Studio Community 2015 support multi-line ES6 template literal (add-ons / hacks / anything)?

**Longer description:**

My problems:

1. Syntax highlighting is wrong
2. It tries to auto-format it, breaking the code

eg. If I put in this valid template literal in a .js file

```
template: `
    <div :id="id" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        Content
    </div>
    `
```

it becomes like this (it highlights it wrongly and breaks the `:id` attribute)

[image]

For now my work-around is to use Notepad++, but it's not ideal.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough, it's really frustrating when software as robust as VS doesn't support highlighting for something simple enough for Notepad++. Worse yet, when the blogs and release notes *claim* to support it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/06/10/javascript-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/